Type not assignable to union of `Extract`ed types containing the type
When trying to call registerCallback() below, seems there's an issue with the type of the argument of the callback itself. The reported error  indicates that the types of the event arg are incompatible, which is unexpected since it seems the types would actually resolve to the same type?
type Events = { type: "e1" } | { type: "e2" };

function registerCallback(cb: (event: Events) => void) {
    console.log(cb);
}

type AddListener = <const EventName extends Events['type']>(eventName: EventName, cb: (event: Extract<Events, {
    type: EventName;
}>) => void) => () => void;

export const addListener: AddListener = (eventName, cb) => {
    console.log(eventName);
    registerCallback(cb);

    return function removeEventListener() {/*...*/ };
}

(playground link)

What you're writing isn't safe and TS is warning you about it.  In AddListener the callback is apparently allowed to assume it's getting only the event corresponding to eventName, but registerCallback() requires that the callback can handle all events. According to your types, this situation can happen, which you can see leads to a runtime error. What is registerCallback actually going to do? (If it's just console.log() then cb can be of type unknown). How does it know which event to pass to the callback? Please [edit] to clarify the intent.
